# PCA and varimax on linear dependent variables

Tags: pca, factor-analysis, multicollinearity, factor-rotation

I am currently trying to use a PCA in combination with a varimax rotation on some measurements to extract underlying factors. However, some of the variables are related, in the sense that they represent percentages or ratios of the possible outcomes. So assume I measure x<sub>{1...N}</sub>,y<sub>{1...N}</sub> and z<sub>{1...N}</sub> all from the same sample, I would now that x<sub>i</sub>+y<sub>i</sub>+z<sub>i</sub>=1 (colinearity between x,y and z for a single measurement).

Now I want to extract underlying factors from these measurements by performing a PCA followed by a varimax rotation. So far I have tried two possibilities, but I am not sure, which one is better.

1. Remove one of the variables from the analysis. For example, I could drop z because it is offering no additional information that is not contained in x and y. In that case of course, I should not perform any kind of scaling before the PCA, because this may remove the colinearity.
2. Keep all variables and therefore also the redundant information, and then perform a PCA on the complete data. In that case, I can also perform scaling of the variables. However, I am not sure here, if the redundancy may impair the PCA.

Maybe there also is a better Analysis method for factor extraction when dealing with ratios. Using the PCA and varimax method I am not so happy that I may have negative loadings, which may be hard to interpret. I believe a NMF may be better suited, but I am not sure, because I have never used NMF before.

Comment: Well, classic PCA can be performed on multicollinear data. Taking this note, why won't that satisfy you?

Comment: @ttnphns I was not totally sure about that, that was the main reason why I asked. I saw that it worked in the sense of the algorithm did not crash, but I was not sure if the resulting data was usable or I might have to be cautious about interpreting the results. Also I am not sure if there are any rules of thumb in the sense that one of the two approaches I considered my be simpler to interpret.

Comment: Please search the site for `PCA multicollinearity`.